# Getting "Entities and POJOs must have a usable public constructor" when using Room database

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Seems like a pretty common error as I was able to find out other questions similar to this one, but can't pinpoint where the issue is.

So I have this Entity

```
@Entity(tableName = "story_id")
data class StoryIdEntity(
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "type")
    val type: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "ids")
    val ids: List<Int>
)
```

And I have this Dao interface

```
@Dao
interface HackerNewsDaoInterface {
    @Query("SELECT ids FROM story_id where type = :type")
    suspend fun getStories(type: String): List<Int>
}
```

When I'm compiling this, I'm getting the following error.

- Entities and POJOs must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type).
- The query returns some columns [ids] which are not used by java.lang.Integer. You can use @ColumnInfo annotation on the fields to specify the mapping.  You can suppress this warning by annotating the method with @SuppressWarnings(RoomWarnings.CURSOR_MISMATCH). Columns returned by the query: ids. Fields in java.lang.Integer:

B/w I've a properly functional type converter for List.

**Update 1**

For the time being I changed the Dao method to make it work.

```
@Dao
interface HackerNewsDaoInterface {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM story_id where type = :type")
    suspend fun getStories(type: String): StoryIdEntity
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a wrapper class for the list of ids, for example:

```
data class StoryIds (
    val ids: List<Int>
)
```

Then modify your query to return an instance of the wrapper class:

```
@Query("SELECT ids FROM story_id where type = :type")
suspend fun getStories(type: String): StoryIds
```

Comment: Don't you feel like this wrapper class is redundant? And what's the issue with accessing the list directly. I believe your solution will work, but what's the problem with my approach?

Comment: As best I can determine from experiments and looking at the code generated by Room, the current version of Room does not support this type of query.   I provided some explanation in a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62272329/4815718).

Comment: Hmm, too bad. At this point, instead of a wrapper, I can return StoryIdEntity itself ‍♂️.

Answer (score -1):

add this to your data class to fix "must have usable public constructor"

```
constructor():this("", ArrayList<Int>())
```